# How to handle large database?

Tags: mysql

I am working in one real-estate website and I have large database around 250 fields in table and 15 lakhs (1.5 million) records in table.  I want to give searching functionality in website so, How should I design db such that I can search property fast from these 15 lakhs records. I want to make site like http://www.redfin.com/.

is it effective all 15 lakhs records should be in one table for searching ?

I don't understand how should I design the db? I am using PHP + Mysql and so I also want to ask that which storage engine(MyISAM,InnoDB etc.) preferred for this type of large database handling ?

Please Help me out.

Comment: What does "15lacks" mean?  I've never seen that before.

Comment: What? A table with 250 columns? why?

Comment: @duffymo: lacks is Indian for a million IIRC

Comment: I don't really understand your question yet. Can you elaborate about your data structure? What do the 250 fields contain? What do you want to manage?

Comment: yes.that table having 250 fields and I want to search on that fields also.

Comment: @Jamiec, thank you.  I didn't know.

Comment: Actually lakh equates to one hundrew thousand.  The next unit up is a crore which is ten miliion.

Comment: While we are on numbers here are some more: sixteen questions, zero acceptances, zero answers, zero votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you saying that your database consists of one table?  That's what 250 fields in a single table suggests to me.  If so, I'd recommend consulting with a design expert to have your schema normalized a bit.

As far as performance goes, MySQL InnoDB should be sufficient as long as you design proper keys and indexes.  The trick will be to know about the queries that you'll need and creating indexes to make them as efficient as possible.

Your table might have 250 columns, but I'm betting that typical queries will go after combinations of columns most of the time.  Those combinations are what you'll need to index.

15 million rows isn't a staggering number.  You might find that normalizing will reduce that number a great deal, because you won't have as much repeated data.  Really large databases measure in terabytes.

Comment: yes sir.that table having 250 fields and I want to search on that fields also.

Comment: set indexes or clustered index on the fields you want to search

Answer (score 1):

## Important points for how to handling large databases

```
--Apply pagination
--Apply Indexing
--Code optimization
--Maintain Dry principle
--Applying Data sharding concept
--Write optimized queries
--Perfect schema design & associations
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to consider normalisation (Google it, read up and then come back and open some new questions if need be).

The number of records has to be very large to affect performance, where very large depends on the RDBMS being used.  E.g. 15 million is huge for Access, mid-range for Oracle.  But the data structure will matter in any RDBMS.  So normalisation is the key.